# Populating the properties of a Picker based on a complex object/model

Tags: c#, .net, maui, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to rebuild a web-application in MAUI.

There is a select-element with 3 different string values.

[image: Dropdown]

This input field relates to the property of an object which has the type int.

[image]

My question is: what would be the best practice to rebuild this input-field in Maui? This is my code so far:

view.xaml

```
<CollectionView Margin="10, 40"
        BindingContext="{x:Reference page}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding gpios}">
[...]
    <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:GPIOView}}, Path=startTypes}"
            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}"/>
</CollectionView>
```

view.xaml.cs

```
public partial class GPIOView : ContentPage
{
    public List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> startTypes { get; } = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> {
        new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "Last Value"),
        new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "On"),
        new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, "Off")
    };
}
```

This works to populate the picker with the correct data. However, I don't know how to set the `Title` property of the picker correctly in order show the user the initial value of the objects property. Also I'm not sure how to update the object property correctly when the selected Item changes.

Comment: you need to bind the picker's `SelectedItem` to a property on your model.

Comment: That's how the Picker works.  Your `SelectedItem` property will need be a `KeyValuePair<int, string>`.  You can create some secondary property that is just the `int` if you prefer.  Or you can use the `SelectedIndexChanged` even instead of the property if you want more control

Comment: I probably need to make a secondary property for the `KeyValuePair<int, string>`, because the `int` property is fixed. It is how I get the object from the backend.

Using `SelectedIndexChanged` will likely not fix the issue of presenting the user the correct initial value.

Comment: Hello, may I ask what platform you use? They have different behaviors.

Comment: For example, on android, the Title acts like a placeholder while on window like a label above the picker

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2022 for Mac and to Debug I use MacCatalyst or iPhone 14 iOS 16.4 usually. Rarely I test it with Pixel 5 on Android 33. The results are not identical, but it is usually sufficient for my use case.

Comment: Anyway, glad you solved it. Your solution is great!

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with, with the help of Jason:

1. I added a secondary property to the underlying Object/Model.

```
public class GPIO 
{
    [...]
    public KeyValuePair<int, string> initialStartType { get; set; }
}
```

2. Before initializing the component in the code-behind, when fetching the Object-Data from the backend, I set this property to a value manually.

```
public List<Services.GPIO> gPIOData { get; set; }
private async void GetGPIOData()
{
    gPIOData = await gPIOService.GetGPIOData();
    foreach(Services.GPIO gpio in gPIOData)
    {
        gpio.initialStartType = startTypes[gpio.pStartType - 1];
    }
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(gPIOData));
}
```

Now I can bind properly in the XAML.

```
<Picker Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:GPIOView}}, Path=startTypes}"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}"
        Title="{Binding initialStartType.Value}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding initialStartType}"/>
```

All I need to do now is to react to the `SelectedItemChange`-Event and re-set the original property of the object.

If anyone has a better approach, a smarter idea or a more elegant solution, I'd be happy to hear/read about it.